# Is there an easy way to find the specification pages for old Apple Computers that have now been removed from the Apple Support pages?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, mac-pro

I recently noticed that it no longer appears possible to view the specifications for old Apple computers directly from the Apple website; their specification pages appear to have been deleted. I'm mainly referring to MacBook/MacBook Pro/iMac/MacBook Air/Mac Pro models produced between 2006 and the current day. I'm aware that multiple third-party websites exist that have this info, but is there an easy-to-find list of archived URLs for the spec pages for these older models that were previously contained on the Apple Support pages?

Comment: If you're referring to the **Technical Specifications** _pages_, they are still there, I just checked. [https://support.apple.com/specs](https://support.apple.com/specs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I recently noticed that it no longer appears possible to view the
>   specifications for old Apple computers directly from the Apple
>   website; their specification pages appear to have been deleted.

If you're referring to the [**Technical Specifications**](https://support.apple.com/specs) *pages*, they are still there. You just have to click the **Load more results** *button* at the bottom of the *page*, until you've reached the *model* you looking for.

---

<sup>**This list current as of May 8, 2020 and are direct links to Apple Tech Support Documents from its website for Mac Notebooks and Mac Desktops back thru 2006:**</sup>

## [Mac Notebooks](https://support.apple.com/specs/macnotebooks)

- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - May 4, 2020](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP818)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - May 4, 2020](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP819)
- [MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020) - Technical Specifications - Mar 18, 2020](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP813)
- [MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) - Technical Specifications - Nov 13, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP809)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - Jun 27, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP799)
- [MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019) - Technical Specifications - Jun 27, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP798)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - May 16, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP795)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2019) - Technical Specifications - May 16, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP794)
- [MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018) - Technical Specifications - Oct 30, 2018](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP783)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) - Technical Specifications - Jul 13, 2018](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP776)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - Jul 13, 2018](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP775)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP755)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754)
- [MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP757)
- [MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP753)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) - Technical Specifications - Nov 15, 2016](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP749)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - Nov 15, 2016](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP748)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) - Technical Specifications - Oct 28, 2016](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP747)
- [MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2016) - Technical Specifications - Apr 20, 2016](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP741)
- [MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) - Technical Specifications - Apr 19, 2016](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP714)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) - Technical Specifications - May 20, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) - Technical Specifications - Mar 10, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP715)
- [MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2015) - Technical Specifications - Mar 10, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP713)
- [MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015) - Technical Specifications - Mar 9, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP712)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014) - Technical Specifications - Jul 30, 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP703)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) - Technical Specifications - Jul 30, 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP704)
- [MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014) - Technical Specifications - Apr 30, 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP700)
- [MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2014) - Technical Specifications - Apr 30, 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP699)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) - Technical Specifications - Oct 24, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP691)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013) - Technical Specifications - Oct 23, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP690)
- [MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013) - Technical Specifications - Jun 10, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP678)
- [MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2013) - Technical Specifications - Jun 10, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP677)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) - Technical Specifications - Feb 19, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP669)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013) - Technical Specifications - Feb 15, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP668)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012) - Technical Specifications - Oct 24, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP658)
- [MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications - Jun 11, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP653)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications - Jun 11, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP649)
- [MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications - Jun 11, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP650)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications - Jun 11, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP694)
- [MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications - Jun 11, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP670)
- [MacBook Pro (17-inch, Late 2011) - Technical Specifications - Oct 24, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP646)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011) - Technical Specifications - Oct 24, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP645)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2011) - Technical Specifications - Oct 24, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP644)
- [MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2011) - Technical Specifications - Jul 21, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP631)
- [MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2011) - Technical Specifications - Jul 21, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP683)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) - Technical Specifications - Feb 25, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP619)
- [MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2011) - Technical Specifications - Feb 25, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP621)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Early 2011) - Technical Specifications - Feb 25, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP620)
- [MacBook Air (13-inch, Late 2010) - Technical Specifications - Oct 20, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP618)
- [MacBook Air (11-inch, Late 2010) - Technical Specifications - Oct 20, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP617)
- [MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - May 21, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP584)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Apr 14, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP583)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Apr 14, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP582)
- [MacBook Pro (17-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Apr 14, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP581)
- [MacBook (13-inch, Late 2009) - Technical Specifications - Oct 20, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP579)
- [MacBook Pro (17-inch, Mid 2009) - Technical Specifications - Jun 9, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP546)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2009) and (15-inch, 2.53 GHz, Mid 2009)  - Technical Specifications - Jun 9, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP544)
- [MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2009) - Technical Specifications - Jun 9, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP541)
- [MacBook Air (Mid 2009) - Technical Specifications - Jun 9, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP548)
- [MacBook (13-inch, Mid 2009) - Technical Specifications - May 27, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP512)
- [MacBook (13-inch, Early 2009) - Technical Specifications - Jan 21, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP504)
- [MacBook Pro (17-inch, Early 2009) - Technical Specifications - Jan 19, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP503)
- [MacBook Air (Late 2008) - Technical Specifications - Nov 4, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP501)
- [MacBook (13-inch, Aluminum, Late 2008) - Technical Specifications - Oct 14, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP500)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch, Late 2008) - Technical Specifications - Oct 14, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP499)
- [MacBook Pro (Early 2008 and Late 2008) - Technical Specifications - Feb 26, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP4)
- [MacBook (Early 2008 and Late 2008) - Technical Specifications - Feb 26, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP5)
- [MacBook Air - Technical Specifications - Jan 15, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP8)
- [MacBook (13-inch, Late 2007) - Technical Specifications - Nov 1, 2007](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP12)
- [MacBook Pro (Late 2007, 2.4/2.2GHz) - Technical Specifications - Nov 1, 2007](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP13)
- [MacBook Pro (Mid 2007, 2.4/2.2GHz) - Technical Specifications - Jun 5, 2007](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP17)
- [MacBook (Mid 2007) - Technical Specifications - May 15, 2007](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP18)
- [MacBook (13-inch, Late 2006) - Technical Specifications - Nov 8, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP23)
- [MacBook Pro (Late 2006) - Technical Specifications - Oct 24, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP24)
- [MacBook - Technical Specifications - May 16, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP31)
- [MacBook Pro (15-inch Glossy) - Technical Specifications - May 16, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP32)
- [MacBook Pro (17-inch) - Technical Specifications - Apr 24, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP33)
- [MacBook Pro (original) - Technical Specifications - Jan 10, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP36)

## [Mac Desktops](https://support.apple.com/specs/macdesktops)

- [Mac Pro (Rack, 2019) - Technical Specifications - Jan 15, 2020](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP810)
- [Mac Pro (2019) - Technical Specifications - Dec 10, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP797)
- [iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2019) - Technical Specifications - Mar 19, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP790)
- [iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, 2019) - Technical Specifications - Mar 19, 2019](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP789)
- [Mac mini (2018) - Technical Specifications - Oct 30, 2018](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP782)
- [iMac Pro (2017) - Technical Specifications - Nov 28, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP771)
- [iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP760)
- [iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP759)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications - Jun 6, 2017](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP758)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2015) - Technical Specifications - Oct 13, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP733)
- [iMac (Retina 4K, 21.5-inch, Late 2015) - Technical Specifications - Oct 13, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP732)
- [iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015) - Technical Specifications - Oct 13, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP731)
- [iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Mid 2015) - Technical Specifications - May 19, 2015](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP718)
- [Mac mini (Late 2014) - Technical Specifications - Oct 16, 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP710)
- [iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) - Technical Specifications - Oct 16, 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP707)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2014) - Technical Specifications - Jun 18, 2014](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP701)
- [Mac Pro (Late 2013) - Technical Specifications - Dec 20, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP697)
- [iMac (27-inch, Late 2013) - Technical Specifications - Sep 25, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP688)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013) - Technical Specifications - Sep 25, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP687)
- [iMac (27-inch, Late 2012) - Technical Specifications - Feb 14, 2013](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP667)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012) - Technical Specifications - Dec 4, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP665)
- [Mac mini Server (Late 2012) - Technical Specifications - Oct 29, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP660)
- [Mac mini (Late 2012) - Technical Specifications - Oct 24, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP659)
- [Mac Pro (Mid 2012) - Technical Specifications - Jun 11, 2012](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP652)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2011) - Technical Specifications - Aug 8, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP634)
- [Mac mini (Mid 2011) - Technical Specifications - Jul 21, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP632)
- [Mac mini Server (Mid 2011) Technical Specifications - Jul 21, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP633)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) - Technical Specifications - May 3, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP623)
- [iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011) - Technical Specifications - May 3, 2011](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP689)
- [Mac Pro (Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Aug 16, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP589)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Jul 27, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP588)
- [iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Jul 27, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP695)
- [Mac mini (Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Jun 15, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP585)
- [Mac mini Server (Mid 2010) - Technical Specifications - Jun 15, 2010](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP586)
- [Mac Pro (Early 2009) - Technical Specifications - Dec 4, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP506)
- [Mac mini (Late 2009) - Technical Specifications - Oct 20, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP577)
- [iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2009) - Technical Specifications - Oct 20, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP576)
- [iMac (27-inch, Late 2009) - Technical Specifications - Oct 20, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP696)
- [Mac mini (Mac OS X Server, Late 2009) - Technical Specifications - Oct 20, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP578)
- [iMac (20-inch, Mid 2009) - Technical Specifications - Apr 7, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP616)
- [iMac (Early 2009) - Technical Specifications - Mar 4, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP507)
- [Mac mini (Early 2009) - Technical Specifications - Mar 3, 2009](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP505)
- [iMac (Early 2008) - Technical Specifications - Apr 28, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP485)
- [Mac Pro (Early 2008) - Technical Specifications - Jan 8, 2008](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP11)
- [iMac (Mid 2007) - Technical Specifications - Aug 7, 2007](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP16)
- [Mac mini (Mid 2007) - Technical Specifications - Aug 7, 2007](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP7)
- [iMac (Late 2006) - Technical Specifications - Sep 6, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP28)
- [Mac mini (Late 2006) - Technical Specifications - Sep 6, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP29)
- [Mac Pro - Technical Specifications - Aug 7, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP30)
- [Mac mini (Early 2006) - Technical Specifications - Feb 28, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP34)
- [iMac (Early 2006) - Technical Specifications - Jan 10, 2006](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP35)

Comment: Just a guess, but on my phone it takes a long time to scroll through...

Answer (score 4):

I find [Mactracker](https://mactracker.ca) to be a very useful app for this. It's available for both macOS and iOS.

The app has technical details for almost all the hardware Apple has ever released all the way back to Apple 1.

Just a fan of the app.

Answer (score 3):

You should go to the web site [EveryMac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple)

It has specifications for most all Macs.  It has info for iMac back to 1998.  The site lists much about the models as well as specs.